# How to create a Textmate like side panel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget

How can I create a side panel like the file explorer in Textmate using C++/Qt? To be more precise like the left side panel in the image below:

[image: textmate side panel]
<sub>(source: [garzaincredible.com](http://garzaincredible.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/624TextMate-Scaled.png))</sub>

The closest thing to my need seems to be `QDockWidget`, but I still didn't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a "Drawer". In Qt, there's a special [`Qt::WindowFlags`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qt.html#WindowType-enum) flag for this: `Qt::Drawer`. The intention is to use this flag on a QDockWidget:

```
QDockWidget* dock = new QDockWidget(parent, Qt::Drawer);
```

This will create a Cocoa drawer for the dock widget. You don't need to make sure that `Qt::Drawer` is only used on OS X; that flag is simply ignored on other platforms, so you can specify it unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way to make it cross platform(for example the app to look the same way also on a Linux machine)?

Comment: @DodonVictor Nope. This is implemented by Cocoa, not Qt. It can't work on other platforms. It wouldn't be a good idea anyway; alien GUI concepts people have never seen before result mostly in confusion. Also, you might want to read this article before you decide to use this Mac feature: http://www.mcelhearn.com/2006/07/29/the-mac-os-x-drawer-a-badly-designed-user-interface-element